# Reduce memory use for a property geolocator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, memory-management, google-maps

I have to run a script against 40 million objects in my database:
I wrote the script and I want 10 instance of it so I process my objects faster.

The goal is to find all the neighborhood for each property.

- A little bit of context: Multiple properties can have the same
  lat/lon.
- A Location is a city.
- I stored all the properties IDs i
  need to process in a separate table because I have a lot more than 40
  millions property and querying that table with `where` conditions if
  really slow even with indexes.
- The reason why I use this
  `Object.const_set("neighborhoods_bp_ids".singularize.classify,
  Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base))` is because I do a lot of processing
  of millions of ids and I don't want to create empty model all over.
  But if that's one big issue with the memory then I can make a proper
  AR class.

But somehow in the code I wrote there is a memory leak or something like this because running all the instances consume all the memory on my server.

property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend GoogleApi

  @proxies = Proxy.all.map(&:ip).shuffle

  self.table_name = 'propertys'
  self.primary_key = 'id'
  self.inheritance_column = :ruby_type #needed to allow 'type' column in db table
  has_and_belongs_to_many :neighborhoods, :limit=>1

  attr_protected

  def self.process_neighborhood(min_id, max_id)
    range = min_id..max_id
    klass = Object.const_set("neighborhoods_bp_ids".singularize.classify, Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base))
    klass.where(id: range).find_in_batches do |group|
      group.each do |bp|
        add_neighborhood(bp.property_id, klass)
        bp.delete
      end
    end
  end

  def self.add_neighborhood(property_id, klass)
    property = Property.find_by_id(property_id)
    if property.present? && property.neighborhoods.blank?
      address = property.full_address.gsub(",", "").squish.present? ? Property.parse_google_geocode(property.full_address) : nil
      if address.present? && address[:neighborhood].present?
        neighborhood = Neighborhood.joins(:location).where("neighborhoods.name =? and locations.city = ? and locations.state = ?",  address[:neighborhood], address[:city], address[:state]).limit(1)
        if neighborhood.blank?
          neighborhood = Neighborhood.find_by_name_and_location_id(address[:neighborhood], nil)
          if neighborhood.blank?
            location = Location.get_closest_known_city(address[:lat], address[:lng], address[:city], address[:state])
            if location.present?
              neighborhood = Neighborhood.create(name: address[:neighborhood], location_id: location.id)
            else
              neighborhood = Neighborhood.create(name: address[:neighborhood])
            end
          end
        else
          neighborhood = neighborhood.first if neighborhood.present?
        end
        begin
          property.neighborhoods << neighborhood if property.neighborhoods.blank?
          all_bps = Property.includes(:neighborhoods).where(latitude: property.latitude, longitude: property.longitude)
          all_bps.each do |u|
            u.neighborhoods << neighborhood if u.neighborhoods.blank?
          end
          klass.delete_all(property_id: all_bps.map(&:id))
        rescue Exception => e
          logger.debug "#{e.class}"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def full_address
    "#{street}, #{city}, #{state} #{zipcode}"
  end

end
```

google_api.rb

```
module GoogleApi
  require 'open-uri'

  PROXY_LOGIN = 'buildzoom'
  PROXY_PASSWORD = 'jonxlord'
  USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"

  def parse_google_geocode(full_address)
      full_address = Rack::Utils.escape(full_address)
      url_full = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#{full_address}"
      proxy = @proxies.first
      begin
        geocode = JSON.parse(open(url_full, :proxy_http_basic_authentication => ["http://#{proxy}", PROXY_LOGIN, PROXY_PASSWORD], "User-Agent" => "HARVESTOR NIGHTMARE V0.1").read)
        if geocode['status'] == "OK"
          if check_geocode(geocode)
            geo = parse_geo(geocode['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
            address = parse_address(geocode['results'][0]['address_components'])
            full_geolocation = address.merge(geo)
            return full_geolocation
          else
            return false
          end
        elsif geocode['status'] == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
          puts "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
          @proxies.rotate!
          parse_google_geocode(full_address)
        elsif geocode['status'] == "ZERO_RESULTS"
          puts "ZERO_RESULTS"
          return {:lat =>nil, :lng => nil, :postal_code => nil}
        else
          return false
        end
      rescue => e
        puts "#{proxy}:#{e}"
        @proxies.rotate!
        parse_google_geocode(full_address)
      end
    end

    def check_geocode(geocode)
      geocode['results'].present? && geocode['results'][0].present? && geocode['results'][0]['geometry'].present? && geocode['results'][0]['geometry']['location'].present? && geocode['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].present? && geocode['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'].present?
    end

    def parse_geo(geo)
      return {:lat =>geo['lat'], :lng => geo['lng']}
    end

    def parse_address(address_components)
      address = {street_number: "", route: "", city: "", state: "", country: "", postal_code: "", neighborhood: ""}
      address_components.each do |ac|
        case ac["types"].first
        when "street_number"
          address[:street_number] = ac["short_name"]
        when "route"
          address[:route] = ac["short_name"]
        when "locality" || "sublocality_level_1"
          address[:city] = ac["long_name"]
        when "sublocality_level_1"
            address[:city] = ac["long_name"]
        when "administrative_area_level_1"
          address[:state] = ac["short_name"]
        when "country"
          address[:country] = ac["short_name"]
        when "postal_code"
          address[:postal_code] = ac["short_name"]
        when "neighborhood"
          address[:neighborhood] = ac["short_name"]
        end
      end
      return address
    end

end
```

To start an instance of the script I run `Property.add_neighborhood(1, 1000000)` for example.

How can I track which parts are consuming all the memory and what can I improve?

I'm using "ruby-2.1.4-railsexpress". I am under the impression that the array rotate for the proxies is the issue. I'm not sure what's the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly rotating the entire `Array` in-place and then calling `#first`, this is \$\Theta(N^2)\$ behavior for a single traversal through the proxy list.

Instead you could create a cyclical `Enumerator` (think Generators in Python) to hold your shuffled proxies and advance it whenever a proxy is over-used. 
This \$\Theta(N)\$ access pattern should reduce memory usage somewhat:

```
 @proxies = Enumerator.new do |fresh_proxies|
   # Using #pluck avoids building intermediate objects before projection
   Proxy.pluck(:ip).shuffle.cycle.each do |proxy|
     fresh_proxies.yield proxy
   end
 end
```

Now you can replace accessing `#first` with:

```
def current_proxy
  @proxies.peek
end
```

and your `#rotate!` with:

```
def advance_to_next_proxy!
  @proxies.next
end
```

Docs:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html